# Principles of creating a canvas application

Tags: javascript, html, facebook, canvas

I have created a few web applications which are more revolved around canvas applications, more specifically, I have created applications that:

- Allow users to drag and drop elements and create images, and save them.

Now there can be some problems when doing so, for example **Responsiveness** of the canvas:

- In the past I created responsive canvas, and the dimensions of the canvas changes according to the user device monitor dimensions, and users were able to use the application in any of their devices.
- But this created some **difficulties designing the web interface**, and problems when sharing the image in facebook, as you all know when sharing links in facebook (the app I created shared links not images) the images appended with it would **not be shown properly**(images being cropped) if they weren't of **standard dimension or ratio** as specified by facebook.
- And since the images created in my application would never have a fixed standard dimensions, satisfactory facebook preview was out of question.

**Have I been following the right principles in developing the applications?**

I always wanted the canvas to have fixed dimensions, but I am bound to give what the client wants, right??

And now I have to create another app, the usual Drag and Drop create images and stuff. But this situation is a bit different, now people will be able to load their own images in the canvas and drag and drop stuffs in them. So here are my problems that can possibly arise:

- First of all since the image is to be uploaded by user, the dimensions will be unknown.
- And the uploaded image will actually be taken as BG for the canvas, if the image is **too small** OR **too big** OR **too rectangular** OR **too square** as compared the current dimension of canvas what am I to do??
- Since the image is supposed to act as the BG, I would need it to fill the whole space, and also wouldn't any part of it to be cropped if its too big for current canvas dimensions.

**How have the HTML5/JS Gurus been solving this problem, I really need some insight in this one!!**

Any help is appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One thing you need is to be able to receive an incoming image with any dimensions and resize that image to the current viewport (canvas-display size) while maintaining the aspect ratio so the image doesn't appear distorted.  Here's a function to do that:

```
function scalePreserveAspectRatio(imgW,imgH,maxW,maxH){
    return(Math.min((maxW/imgW),(maxH/imgH)));
}
```

When you're drawing the image on the screen-sized canvas, you use the scaling version of context.drawImage like this:

```
var iw=image.width;
var ih=image.height;
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

var scale=scalePreserveAspectRatio(iw,ih,cw,ch);

context.drawImage(image, 0,0,iw,ih, 0,0,iw*scale,ih*scale);
```

And Yes...

If the received image is not proportioned the same as the canvas-display then some part of the image will not fit in the canvas-display. A square image will not fit exactly inside a rectangular display no matter how you resize the image.

Therefore, you must then make a design decision of how to deal with this disproportion.

- Draw the scaled image at the top-left of the canvas which lets the overflow part of the received image become clipped.
- Center the scaled image on the canvas which lets the image be equally clipped on the outer sides of the image. The idea is that the most interesting part of the image is probably near the center of the image and the least interesting part of the image is on it's sides.
- Forget proportional scaling and just scale the image vertically & horizontally to exactly fit the canvas-display dimensions.  This will result in a distorted image.  But no part of the image will be clipped off.  If the distortion is not large, this might be a useful option.
- Scale the image so that the entire image fits in the canvas-display.  This will result in a portion of the canvas-display being blank.  This is what televisions often do when displaying the older (squarer) TV programs on a wide-screen TV.

Good luck with your project!